# Unable to use "root.top-self.height" for placement properly in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a menu using box layout in kivy. I wanted to use "root.top-self.height" so that it sticks the vertical layout from the top of screen but its still sticking from bottom. Also when I print(root.top) its strangely giving 100 which is not my screen resolution. Please let me know how can I place it accurately. 
Furthermore I read somewhere that I need to use root=BoxLayout(), now after using this the button's are not clickable after adding that, before adding this I could use the buttons. Please do let me know how to deal with "root" ie screen or App size functionality.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.label import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.layout import Layout
from  kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder



## CREATING A CLASS WHICH HAS SCREEN CONTENT:
class firstScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(firstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        root = BoxLayout()
        self.pos = (0 ,root.top-self.height)
        print(root.top)

        self.myButton1 = Button(text='Home',
                              color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,None),
##                              pos_hint = {'x':.8, 'y':'.7'},
##                              pos_hint = {'x':0, 'top':'0'},
                              pos = (0,0)
                              )
        self.myButton2 = Button(text='Buy Now',
                                color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,None))
        self.myButton3 = Button(text='Blog',
                                color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,None))
        self.myButton4 = Button(text='Contant Us',
                                color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,None))

        self.add_widget(self.myButton1)
        self.add_widget(self.myButton2)
        self.add_widget(self.myButton3)
        self.add_widget(self.myButton4)

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        print(touch)
    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        print(touch)
    def on_touch_up(self,touch):
        print(touch)

## CREATING A CLASS WHICH RETURNS SOME SCREEN:
class myKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return firstScreen()

## THIS CODE RUNS THE CLASS WHICH HAS SOME SCREEN
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myKivyApp().run()
```

Comment: Your `firstScreen` is a `BoxLayout`, but your line `root = BoxLayout()` creates another `BoxLayout`. What is your intention for that second `BoxLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminating the unused `BoxLayout` and setting the `y` component of `size_hint` to `1.0` means that each button will share equally in the vertical space available for the `firstScreen`.

```
class firstScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(firstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.myButton1 = Button(text='Home',
                              color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,1.0))
        self.myButton2 = Button(text='Buy Now',
                                color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,1.0))
        self.myButton3 = Button(text='Blog',
                                color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,1.0))
        self.myButton4 = Button(text='Contant Us',
                                color = (1,0,0,1),
                              size_hint = (0.1,1.0))

        self.add_widget(self.myButton1)
        self.add_widget(self.myButton2)
        self.add_widget(self.myButton3)
        self.add_widget(self.myButton4)
```

By the way, the `root.top` will always be `100` in the `__init__()` method. The `100` is the default value and is not updated until the app is actually displayed.